# PostgreSQL - Invalid input syntax for integer

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, casting

I have made composite type named t_user_type:

```
CREATE TYPE t_user_type AS
   (uid integer,
    firstname character varying,
    lastname character varying,
    companyname character varying,
    email character varying,
    sip_phone integer);
```

...and I need to cast string to that type, so I do

```
SELECT '(11423, FirstName, LastName, Company, email@gmail.com, 204)' :: t_user_type;
```

everythin is fine. No errors, nothing. But when I do that same thing using procedure, I get this error: *Invalid input syntax for integer: "(11423," FirstName"," LastName"," Company"," email@gmail.com", 204)"*.

Here is my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_type(p_user character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$DECLARE
  v_user_type t_user_type;
BEGIN
  SELECT p_user :: t_user_type INTO v_user_type;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION change_type(character varying)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

And here is query that uses the procedure:

```
SELECT change_type(
   '(11423, FirstName, LastName, Company, email@gmail.com, 204)');
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you also add what version of Postgres you are on?

Comment: I'm using 9.3, and pgAdmin 1.18.0.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why that fails I made small change where I just cast the value into your local variable and it appears to work.  But I don't know why yet.  Is it legal to SELECT INTO a variable like you were doing(I think so I can do it with regular text string into a text variable)?  I usually do it like my example below when it's just a variable with no source table.

```
CREATE TYPE t_user_type AS
   (uid integer,
    firstname character varying,
    lastname character varying,
    companyname character varying,
    email character varying,
    sip_phone integer);

SELECT '(11423, FirstName, LastName, Company, email@gmail.com, 204)' :: t_user_type;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_type(p_user character varying)
  RETURNS t_user_type AS
$BODY$DECLARE
  v_user_type t_user_type;
BEGIN
  v_user_type := CAST(p_user AS t_user_type);
  return v_user_type;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION change_type(character varying)
OWNER TO postgres;

SELECT change_type(
   '(11423, FirstName, LastName, Company, email@gmail.com, 204)');
```

Comment: I tried casting data like you did, and it works! Thank you!
I always do my SELECT INTO like this, and postgres never complains.